# Generar combinaciones de un string dada una lista

Tags: condiciones, bucles, algoritmos

He estado optimizando un diccionario para calcular una contraseña
y aumentar las posibilidades de encontrarla a través de fuerza bruta.

Como una lista con los elementos a iterar con el string nombre.

```
I = ('iI')
S = ('sS')
A = ('aA')
b = ('bB')
e = ('Ee')
L = ('Ll')
```

Como seria mejor generar las combinaciones iterando la lista I,
luego la S, A, B, E, L ? En orden y sin repetir por supuesto.
Este es un ejemplo de como se veria el resultado de algunas palabras
generadas. Una luz por favor, muchas gracias desde ya.

iSaBel
ISABEL
IsabeL

Answer (score 0):

Lo que tienes que hacer es un **producto carteciano** de arreglos, hay muchas formas de hacerlo, siempre la idea es recorrer, por cada elemento, todos los demas elementos de los demás arreglos en orden, para ello habría que hacer un for dentro de otro por cada arreglo. Como esto es engorroso y por cada elemento deberíamos agregar un for mas, se puede usar la recursión:

Aquí dejo un ejemplo en JavaScript lo mas agnóstico posible, en cualquier caso los datos iniciales deberían ser un arreglo de arreglos.

```js
const lista = [
  ['i', 'I'],
  ['s', 'S'],
  ['a', 'A'],
  ['b', 'B'],
  ['E', 'e'],
  ['L', 'l']
];


function combinaciones(arr) {

  if (arr.length == 1) {
    return arr[0];
  }

  let comparacion1 = arr[0]; // Siempre es la primera posicion de lo que venga

  let sacamosLaPrimeraPosicion = arr.splice(1); //siempre es desde la posicion 1 al final

  let comparacion2 = combinaciones(sacamosLaPrimeraPosicion);

  let palabras = []

  for (let i = 0; i < comparacion1.length; i++) {

    for (let j = 0; j < comparacion2.length; j++) {

      palabras.push(comparacion1[i] + comparacion2[j]) // se va agregando de la última a la primera

    }

  }

  return palabras;

}


const res = combinaciones(lista);

console.log(res);
```